# WPF UserControl Child Component Event Handler

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, events

I have a UserControl that contain let's say a button (or any other object).

```
<UserControl x:Class="StackOverFlowQuestion.UserControlButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverFlowQuestion"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button
            x:Name="Button1"
            Content="Click me for testing"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and I want to access that Button's(Or any Object) Click Event or any Event form the parent that contains the UserControl.

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverFlowQuestion.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverFlowQuestion"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <local:UserControlButton/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Access it how and from where? The XAML? Or the code?

Comment: access it be the meaning of adding an event handler form the xaml code

Comment: It's not possible to hook up an event handler to the `Button` that is defined in the `UserControl` from in XAML markup of the window. You will then need to define an event in the `UserControl` class.

Comment: That's exactly what I did, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy. Just put a public event to the `UserControl` (code behind) for it could be accessible from outside of UserControl and do forward the Click event from your button.

```
public partial class UserControlButton : UserControl
{
    public event RoutedEventHandler ButtonClick;

    private void UsrCtlButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ButtonClick?.Invoke(sender, e);
    }
}
```

XAML of `UserControl`:

```
<Button x:Name="Button1" Content="Click me for testing" Click="UsrCtlButton_Click"/>
```

XAML where `UserControl` being used:

```
<local:UserControlButton ButtonClick="Some_event_handler_to_handle_Button_Click"/>
```

Comment: Cheers mate, that's what I have been looking for.